# PHP mail Form redirect URL doesn't work. Webpage is here. (Tried other "SOF" answers)

Tags: php, html, forms

first of all, I have to say this.I used "Wix" for my website but since it doesn't have function to [img] tag with percentage width.So now I have started making my own website, and that's about 1month ago, when I only knew how to [img src], without any other html knowledge. I forced myself to make this myself so I can make my website exactly as what I want, and now it seems almost done as I uploaded on my hosting server.

The problem is, in my 'order page', after filling out the form, and press 'submit button', it doesn't show the page I attended to show. Just turns out to the first part of order page.

the code I tried is

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
if($formproc->ProcessForm())
{
    $formproc->RedirectToURL("http://ljhbunkercom.ipage.com/index/thank-you.php");
}
```

when fully filled form gets submitted with the submit button, it really sends every information to my mailbox, but thank-you.php doesn't show up.

I tried

```
 if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
    if($formproc->ProcessForm())
    {
        $formproc->header("Location: http://ljhbunkercom.ipage.com/index/thank-you.php");
   }
```

( the change is , redirect url -> header location.)

and also, not showing the thank-you page.

I modified free open email form source into my own order page, by combining another open source.

-->http://www.sanwebe.com/2014/04/ajax-contact-form-attachment-jquery-php

this is the source I used, but this works  so fine. when filled out all the input text box and pressed the submit button, it shows the thank-you.php.

I think I did something wrong, when I modified it.

I remember I changed this, 
htmlentities-> htmlspecialchars 
but I don't think this really does that effect.

please help .

My web orderpage is this .
http://ljhbunkercom.ipage.com/index/order.php

(! please do not hack my webpage.  )

****What is the problem, and how can I make it show the thank-you.php page when required information have been submitted??****

## ============== The form class==========

```
    class FG_CaptchaHandler
{
    function Validate() { return false;}
    function GetError(){ return '';}
}
/*
FGContactForm is a general purpose contact form class
It supports Captcha, HTML Emails, sending emails
conditionally, File atachments and more.
*/
class FGContactForm
{
    var $receipients;
    var $errors;
    var $error_message;
    var $name;
    var $email;
    var $message;
    var $from_address;
    var $form_random_key;
    var $conditional_field;
    var $arr_conditional_receipients;
    var $fileupload_fields;
    var $captcha_handler;

    var $mailer;

    function FGContactForm()
    {
        $this->receipients = array();
        $this->errors = array();
        $this->form_random_key = 'xxxxxxx';
        $this->conditional_field='';
        $this->arr_conditional_receipients=array();
        $this->fileupload_fields=array();

        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer();
        $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    }

    function EnableCaptcha($captcha_handler)
    {
        $this->captcha_handler = $captcha_handler;
        session_start();
    }

    function AddRecipient($email,$name="")
    {
        $this->mailer->AddAddress($email,$name);
    }

    function SetFromAddress($from)
    {
        $this->from_address = $from;
    }
    function SetFormRandomKey($key)
    {
        $this->form_random_key = $key;
    }
    function GetSpamTrapInputName()
    {
        return 'sp'.md5('xxxxxxxxx'.$this->GetKey());
    }
    function SafeDisplay($value_name)
    {
        if(empty($_POST[$value_name]))
        {
            return'';
        }
        return htmlspecialchars($_POST[$value_name]);
    }
    function GetFormIDInputName()
    {
        $rand = md5('xxxxxxx'.$this->GetKey());

        $rand = substr($rand,0,20);
        return 'id'.$rand;
    }


    function GetFormIDInputValue()
    {
        return md5('xxxxxxx'.$this->GetKey());
    }

    function SetConditionalField($field)
    {
        $this->conditional_field = $field;
    }
    function AddConditionalReceipent($value,$email)
    {
        $this->arr_conditional_receipients[$value] =  $email;
    }

    function AddFileUploadField($file_field_name,$accepted_types,$max_size)
    {

        $this->fileupload_fields[] =
            array("name"=>$file_field_name,
            "file_types"=>$accepted_types,
            "maxsize"=>$max_size);
    }

    function ProcessForm()
    {
        if(!isset($_POST['submitted']))
        {
           return false;
        }
        if(!$this->Validate())
        {
            $this->error_message = implode('<br/>',$this->errors);
            return false;
        }
        $this->CollectData();

        $ret = $this->SendFormSubmission();

        return $ret;
    }

    function RedirectToURL($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;
    }

    function GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $this->error_message;
    }
    function GetSelfScript()
    {
        return htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }

    function GetName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    function GetEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
    function GetMessage()
    {
        return htmlspecialchars($this->message,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
    }

/*--------  Private (Internal) Functions -------- */


    function SendFormSubmission()
    {
        $this->CollectConditionalReceipients();

        $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $this->mailer->Subject = "Contact form submission from $this->name";

        $this->mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();

        $this->mailer->FromName = $this->name;

        $this->mailer->AddReplyTo($this->email);

        $message = $this->ComposeFormtoEmail();

        $textMsg = trim(strip_tags(preg_replace('/<(head|title|style|script)[^>]*>.*?<\/\\1>/s','',$message)));
        $this->mailer->AltBody = @html_entity_decode($textMsg,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
        $this->mailer->MsgHTML($message);

        $this->AttachFiles();

        if(!$this->mailer->Send())
        {
            $this->add_error("알수없는 이유로 메일보내기가 실패하였습니다. LJHBUNKER@LJHBUNKER.COM 으로 연락주시길 바랍니다!");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    function CollectConditionalReceipients()
    {
        if(count($this->arr_conditional_receipients)>0 &&
          !empty($this->conditional_field) &&
          !empty($_POST[$this->conditional_field]))
        {
            foreach($this->arr_conditional_receipients as $condn => $rec)
            {
                if(strcasecmp($condn,$_POST[$this->conditional_field])==0 &&
                !empty($rec))
                {
                    $this->AddRecipient($rec);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    Internal variables, that you donot want to appear in the email
    Add those variables in this array.
    */
    function IsInternalVariable($varname)
    {
        $arr_interanl_vars = array('scaptcha',
                            'submitted',
                            $this->GetSpamTrapInputName(),
                            $this->GetFormIDInputName()
                            );
        if(in_array($varname,$arr_interanl_vars))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function FormSubmissionToMail()
    {
        $ret_str='';
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        {
            if(!$this->IsInternalVariable($key))
            {
                $value = htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
                $value = nl2br($value);
                $key = ucfirst($key);
                $ret_str .= "<div class='label'>$key :</div><div class='value'>$value </div>\n";
            }
        }
        foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upload_field)
        {
            $field_name = $upload_field["name"];
            if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
            {
                continue;
            }        

            $filename = basename($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);

            $ret_str .= "<div class='label'>File upload '$field_name' :</div><div class='value'>$filename </div>\n";
        }
        return $ret_str;
    }

    function ExtraInfoToMail()
    {
        $ret_str='';

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $ret_str = "<div class='label'>IP address of the submitter:</div><div class='value'>$ip</div>\n";

        return $ret_str;
    }

    function GetMailStyle()
    {
        $retstr = "\n<style>".
        "body,.label,.value { font-family:Arial,Verdana; } ".
        ".label {font-weight:bold; margin-top:5px; font-size:1em; color:#333;} ".
        ".value {margin-bottom:15px;font-size:0.8em;padding-left:5px;} ".
        "</style>\n";

        return $retstr;
    }
    function GetHTMLHeaderPart()
    {
         $retstr = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">'."\n".
                   '<html><head><title></title>'.
                   '<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">';
         $retstr .= $this->GetMailStyle();
         $retstr .= '</head><body>';
         return $retstr;
    }
    function GetHTMLFooterPart()
    {
        $retstr ='</body></html>';
        return $retstr ;
    }
    function ComposeFormtoEmail()
    {
        $header = $this->GetHTMLHeaderPart();
        $formsubmission = $this->FormSubmissionToMail();
        $extra_info = $this->ExtraInfoToMail();
        $footer = $this->GetHTMLFooterPart();

        $message = $header."Submission from 'contact us' form:<p>$formsubmission</p><hr/>$extra_info".$footer;

        return $message;
    }

    function AttachFiles()
    {
        foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upld_field)
        {
            $field_name = $upld_field["name"];
            if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
            {
                continue;
            }

            $filename =basename($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);

            $this->mailer->AddAttachment($_FILES[$field_name]["tmp_name"],$filename);
        }
    }

    function GetFromAddress()
    {
        if(!empty($this->from_address))
        {
            return $this->from_address;
        }

        $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

        $from ="nobody@$host";
        return $from;
    }

    function Validate()
    {
        $ret = true;
        //security validations
        if(empty($_POST[$this->GetFormIDInputName()]) ||
          $_POST[$this->GetFormIDInputName()] != $this->GetFormIDInputValue() )
        {
            //The proper error is not given intentionally
            $this->add_error("Automated submission prevention: case 1 failed");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //This is a hidden input field. Humans won't fill this field.
        if(!empty($_POST[$this->GetSpamTrapInputName()]) )
        {
            //The proper error is not given intentionally
            $this->add_error("Automated submission prevention: case 2 failed");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //name validations
        if(empty($_POST['name']))
        {
            $this->add_error("&nbsp;&nbsp;이름을 기재하여주세요!&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(strlen($_POST['name'])>50)
        {
            $this->add_error("&nbsp;&nbsp;이름을 정확히 기재하여 주세요!&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //email validations
        if(empty($_POST['email']))
        {
            $this->add_error("&nbsp;&nbsp;E-mail 주소가 입력되지 않았습니다!&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(strlen($_POST['email'])>50)
        {
            $this->add_error("&nbsp;&nbsp;올바른 E-mail 주소를 &ldquo;정확히&rdquo; 입력하여주세요!&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(!$this->validate_email($_POST['email']))
        {
            $this->add_error("&nbsp;&nbsp;올바른 E-mail 주소를 &ldquo;정확히&rdquo; 입력하여주세요!&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //check validations
        if(empty($_POST['message0']))
        {
            $this->add_error("&nbsp;&nbsp;용도를 기입하여 주세요!&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //message validaions
        if(strlen($_POST['message2'])>2048)
        {
            $this->add_error("&nbsp;&nbsp;추가 코멘트가 너무 깁니다! 500자 이내의 분량만 수용이 가능합니다.&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //file validations
        if($_FILES['photo']['size'] == 0 )
        {
            $this->add_error("&nbsp;&nbsp;스케치가 첨부되지 않았습니다!&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //check validations 
        if(empty($_POST['check']))
        {
            $this->add_error("&nbsp;&nbsp;커스텀 일러스트 Type을 선택하여주세요!&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            $ret = false;
        }


        //captcha validaions
        if(isset($this->captcha_handler))
        {
            if(!$this->captcha_handler->Validate())
            {
                $this->add_error($this->captcha_handler->GetError());
                $ret = false;
            }
        }
        //file upload validations
        if(!empty($this->fileupload_fields))
        {
         if(!$this->ValidateFileUploads())
         {
            $ret = false;
         }
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function ValidateFileType($field_name,$valid_filetypes)
    {
        $ret=true;
        $info = pathinfo($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);
        $extn = $info['extension'];
        $extn = strtolower($extn);

        $arr_valid_filetypes= explode(',',$valid_filetypes);
        if(!in_array($extn,$arr_valid_filetypes))
        {
            $this->add_error("Valid file types are: $valid_filetypes");
            $ret=false;
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function ValidateFileSize($field_name,$max_size)
    {
        $size_of_uploaded_file =
                $_FILES[$field_name]["size"]/4096;//size in KBs
        if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_size)
        {
            $this->add_error("스케치파일의 용량이 너무 큽니다! (4메가 초과) ");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function IsFileUploaded($field_name)
    {
        if(empty($_FILES[$field_name]['name']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function ValidateFileUploads()
    {
        $ret=true;
        foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upld_field)
        {
            $field_name = $upld_field["name"];

            $valid_filetypes = $upld_field["file_types"];

            if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if($_FILES[$field_name]["error"] != 0)
            {
                $this->add_error("Error in file upload; Error code:".$_FILES[$field_name]["error"]);
                $ret=false;
            }

            if(!empty($valid_filetypes) &&
             !$this->ValidateFileType($field_name,$valid_filetypes))
            {
                $ret=false;
            }

            if(!empty($upld_field["maxsize"]) &&
            $upld_field["maxsize"]>0)
            {
                if(!$this->ValidateFileSize($field_name,$upld_field["maxsize"]))
                {
                    $ret=false;
                }
            }

        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function StripSlashes($str)
    {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return $str;
    }
    /*
    Sanitize() function removes any potential threat from the
    data submitted. Prevents email injections or any other hacker attempts.
    if $remove_nl is true, newline chracters are removed from the input.
    */
    function Sanitize($str,$remove_nl=true)
    {
        $str = $this->StripSlashes($str);

        if($remove_nl)
        {
            $injections = array('/(\n+)/i',
                '/(\r+)/i',
                '/(\t+)/i',
                '/(%0A+)/i',
                '/(%0D+)/i',
                '/(%08+)/i',
                '/(%09+)/i'
                );
            $str = preg_replace($injections,'',$str);
        }

        return $str;
    }

    /*Collects clean data from the $_POST array and keeps in internal variables.*/
    function CollectData()
    {
        $this->name = $this->Sanitize($_POST['name']);
        $this->email = $this->Sanitize($_POST['email']);
        $this->check = $this->Sanitize($_POST['check']);

        /*newline is OK in the message.*/
        $this->message0 = $this->StripSlashes($_POST['message0']);
        $this->message2 = $this->StripSlashes($_POST['message2']);
    }

    function add_error($error)
    {
        array_push($this->errors,$error);
    }
    function validate_email($email)
    {
        return eregi("^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", $email);
    }

    function GetKey()
    {
        return $this->form_random_key.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

}
```

(Please Please let me know if I just wrote something that should be kept unshown on public..)

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add:  `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: @dagon thank you for the comment. I added that thankful comment right away, but still it does the same. oh and I am sorry I editted my question now. it 's now, not showing the white blank page, but now it shows the first part of the orderpage while I want it to show the thank-you.php (maybe it had a little bit of progress). even after following your direction, it does the same. it sill shows the first part. 
I will try to dig it out more myself, and thank you for the comment.

Comment: The source code you've used indicates that it's using AJAX to handle the form submission. Did you omit the AJAX portion of favor of submitting directly to the server? Also, can we see what's in this class $formproc?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy sorry for not giving enough information at first, and thank you for trying to help me out. I just editted my post again, and now it has the information you asked, (is .. it ..right?)

Comment: @dagon I made it show white blank page, and used your code, and now it shows :Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /hermes/bosweb25c/b1898/ipg.ljhbunkercom/index/order/examples/include/fgcontactform.php on line 575 Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in /hermes/bosweb25c/b1898/ipg.ljhbunkercom/index/order/examples/include/class.phpmailer.php on line 1218 Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in

Comment: @dagon continued ) /hermes/bosweb25c/b1898/ipg.ljhbunkercom/index/order/examples/include/class.phpmailer.php on line 1222 Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /hermes/bosweb25c/b1898/ipg.ljhbunkercom/index/order/examples/include/class.phpmailer.php on line 470 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb25c/b1898/ipg.ljhbunkercom/index/order/examples/include/fgcontactform.php:3) in /hermes/bosweb25c/b1898/ipg.ljhbunkercom/index/order/examples/include/fgcontactform.php on line 146

Comment: well you need to fix all those errors